# Is there a preferred panel chart layout?

Tags: data-visualization

I have a panel chart composed of 4 panels, each with 12 bars that essentially show data from a pivot table.  The default layout has the first 11 rows show individual points, with the 12th row showing a total of the entire column.  Similarly, the final column shows a total of the 3 preceding columns.  The result is the total for all values is bottom right, like in pivot table.

My question is whether there's a benefit or preferred method to rearranging the panels and data points so that the aggregate data is top left in the chart, making it the first value seen (in traditional left-right, top-bottom reading), or keeping the more traditional mathematic approach with totals at the bottom and to the right?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

After a great deal of experimenting and googling (to no avail), I've decided for a quasi-dashboard application (which this is), that having the aggregate column at left and row at top makes the most sense for my users.  It's taking me-and my pivot table experience-a while to get used to it, but left-right, top-bottom organization seems to make the most sense for my other users.  Still open to anyone elses comments.

Comment: It's not the best reasoned answer (and I have nothing substantive to back it up), but it's working for now.  If anyone has a better one, please let me know and I'm happy to open it back up.